# Single word meaning "becoming lost or forgotten"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that means "becoming lost or forgotten," much like how [*obsolescent*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obsolescent) means "becoming obsolete" or how [*moribund*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/moribund) means "approaching death; dying." I want to use it in the sense that certain knowledge of the past is becoming lost/forgotten. A sample sentence follows:

> "It is a shame that certain traditional customs are [adjectival form of word meaning "becoming lost/forgotten"].

When I say I want a word meaning “becoming lost/forgotten,” I mean to say that the word should connote something that is in the process of becoming less known. In other words, the word I am looking for should mean “in the process of becoming lost or forgotten.” I am trying to be as specific as possible.

Thank you

PS: My example about “obsolescent” is a perfect instance of what the word I’m looking for should be like.

Comment: ....are disappearing.

Comment: ..... are dying.

Comment: You may use “forgotten”.

Comment: Ironically, I would use *obsolete* . . .

Comment: @JasonBassford But *obsolete* doesn’t at all mean “becoming lost.” It means “no longer in use or no longer useful.”

Comment: What you asked for was "something that is no longer known because of age or neglect" and "becoming lost because of disuse or because of a lack of continuity." The word *obsolete* fits that. It's something that has been neglected, put aside, and forgotten about.

Comment: The word I want *has* to mean "**becoming** lost," just as *obsolescent* means "becoming obsolete." You could also say the word I’m looking for means “in the process of becoming lost or forgotten.”

Comment: In which case, *obsolescent* works just as well for the descriptions you've given. If you want to stress **lost** specifically, you need to remove or edit your last paragraph.

Comment: What you're asking is tricky. You want a word meaning something like "becoming lost", "becoming forgotten", "becoming obsolete", so you need either an adjective which specifically describes an undergoing process of being forgotten, or any of various present participles of an intransitive verb. The "becoming" part will be included in the present participle as the progressive aspect, ie., "are obsolescing" https://www.thefreedictionary.com/obsolesce

Comment: @Zebrafish *Obsolescent* is an adjective meaning “becoming obsolete.” I want a similar word in both function and definition, just meaning “becoming lost.” Am I not being clear? Maybe I’m not explaining enough...

Comment: Lost in time, space, memory or what...all above suggestions fit your context.

Comment: @user240918 Preferably, I would like a **single word**, like, I say again, [“obsolescent”](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obsolescent).

Comment: @Zebrafish [“Obsolesce,”](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obsolesce) when used transitively, means “to make obsolescent.” When used intransitively, it means “to be or become obsolescent.” The key word is “obsolescent.” The word I want can have a verbal form, as well as an adjectival one.

Comment: Sorry if I insist, but “disappearing” is a term often associated with traditions that are “becoming lost”. https://www.google.it/search?rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT753IT753&ei=A6vFW_qoBaX5qwGeuKngCA&q=traditions+that+are+disappering&oq=traditions+that+are+disappering&gs_l=mobile-gws-wiz-serp.3..33i160.34745.48279..48564...6.0..3.978.11115.0j17j3j5j2j2j5......0....1.......3..0j41j46j46i67j0i67j0i10i19j0i30i19j0i5i10i30i19j0i131j46i131j0i131i67j0i22i30j0i19j0i22i30i19j33i22i29i30j33i21.XHBLCRBOo6I&pccc=1

Comment: @user240918 You might have a point. If you can post this as an answer, I will take it under consideration.

Answer (score 5):

How about "**waning**"?

"**It is a shame that certain traditional customs are waning**"

From Merriam-Websters dictionary:

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wane

> ### wane
>
> verb
>   \ˈwān\
>   waned; waning
>
> Definition of wane
>
> Intransitive Verb
>
> (Entry 2 of 2)
>
> 2: to fall gradually from power, prosperity, or influence

Here, falling from influence is apt.

Comment: “Waning” implies weakening, not becoming lost.

Comment: More options: petering out, atrophying, crumbling, collapsing

Comment: "It is a shame that certain traditional customs are collapsing". I think this meets the conditions closely because collapsing implies not only the present situation but forecasts the future too. Let's think about what happens when something collapses? It becomes lost.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Note that Stack Exchange answers are “right” answers, not ideas, suggestions, or opinions. To show that yours is the right answer, please edit to include an explanation, context, and supporting facts, such as the definition from a good online dictionary. This is what makes answers useful – to the asker, and to future visitors. See: [“Real questions have answers, not items or ideas or opinions”]( https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/).

Answer (score 2):

"It is a shame that certain traditional customs are **fading**."

From Merriam-Webster's definition of [fade](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fade):

> **1** : to lose freshness, strength, or vitality : WITHER
>   // *fading* flowers
>   **2** : to lose freshness or brilliance of color
>   // The fabrics *faded* in the strong sunshine.
>   **3** : to sink away : VANISH
>   // a *fading* memory
>   // The smile *faded* from his face.

Comment: This is pretty close, although not exactly there. Thank you; I will take it under consideration!

Answer (score 2):

As single words I came up with these (hopefully in order of suitability): **dwindling, declining, waning, and diminishing**.

> "It is a shame that certain traditional customs are **dwindling**.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/dwindle

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/declining

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/wane

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/diminishing

In two words, using the word "becoming _____" the possibilities increase, but that is not your question. Perhaps **bygone** would work as an example.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/bygone

Answer (score 1):

**Declining**

adjective
1. 
deteriorating gradually, as in quality, health, or character
… a declining birth rate.
he's in declining health
a declining industry
https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/declining

"It is a shame that certain traditional customs are declining"

Or

"It is a shame that certain traditional customs are in decline."

Answer (score -1):

***lost***
is the right word here, as in:

> 4) **lost traditions**
>   Syn: … forgotten, consigned to oblivion, extinct, dead, gone
>   © *Academic*, 2000-2017, http://thesaurus_en.enacademic.com/7644

The sentence in context would be:

> "It is a shame that certain traditional customs are **being lost** (to posterity)".

Comment: Yes, “lost” means “lost.” I need a word meaning “in the process of becoming lost,” i.e. not yet lost. See my example about “obsolescent.”

Comment: Replace *becoming* with *being* and that should work.

Comment: Of course it would work. But that isn’t what I’m looking for. Just as “obsolescent” means “**becoming** obsolete,” I want word meaning “becoming lost.” If no such word exists, I’ll have to go with “disappearing” or “fading,” as others have suggested.

Comment: *Lost* is not only a verb but also an adjective. So you don't need an adjective form of *lost*.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But “obsolescent” is an adjective and look what it means. There’s a link in my question.